# ASUS Z97-C Compatible With TP-Link TL-WDN4800

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard

I have a ASUS Z97-C Motherboard, and I want to add a wireless network card.

I was wondering if the TP-Link TL-WDN4800 802.11a is ccompatible with my motherboard?

[image]

Comment: If your motherboard has a free PCIe slot it should work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is not a forum about hardware compatibility. Well, let's see.

A wireless card needs a wireless 450 Mbps issued at this speed, and do not know if it's your case. Therefore, even faster than the card, if the only issues to 54Mbps wifi will not notice improvement.

If your computer has a PCI slot free, you can use it, another thing is that the operating system detects that you have installed and have no conflict of drivers.

Another solution, faster, convenient and cheap, is to buy a USB wireless receiver.

Comment: This is a PCIe card, not a PCI card. Your second paragraph makes no sense at all. Finally, USB receivers are not necessary (and in fact, not generally) faster.

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to the OP's question... The user did not ask about the speed compatibility. Secondly, yes, the user could plug the card into a PCI slot, but why use a PCI slot if the user has 4 PCIe slots to choose from (assuming they're not using any currently). Generally, also, a USB adapter would not be any faster.

Comment: Faster if we talk about compatibility checkings before buying. Bad explain..

Comment: "faster if we talk about compatibility" - that would be more convenient, rather than faster.

Comment: I tried to find best solution. If he is unable to find out if a hardware component is compatible with his motherboard, maybe he buy a WIFI card  that not is needed. Maybe he thinks his Internet go faster by buying a faster wireless card, and is not, and depends on many more factors.